# How to select a line without selecting the line break at the end of it in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext

When I click on the line number at the left or if I triple click the text in the line, I don't want the following new line/line break to be selected. Is there any simple way to change the settings for this? It would save a lot of time when copying/pasting.

Comment: So you only want this for single line selections, correct? If you select multiple lines, you still want the newlines included?

Comment: @MattDMo, When selecting one line, I don't want the newline at the end to be selected. When selecting multiple lines, I only want the last newline to not get selected.

Answer (score 1):

This won't help with clicking on the line number, but here's how you can change the triple-click. In `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap`, the triple-click is defined like this:

```
    // Drag select by lines
    {
        "button": "button1", "count": 3,
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "lines"},
    },
```

You can override that definition by creating a corresponding `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` file in your User package, and then redefine it like this:

```
[
    // Drag select by lines
    {
        "button": "button1", "count": 3,
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "lines"},
        "command": "move",
        "args": {"by": "characters", "extend": true, "forward": false}
    },
]
```

Note: The press_command/press_args lines are what happens on the button's way down (the third time in this case). Adding the command/args lines tells it what to do when the button comes back up.

Likewise, you can define an alternative to the `Expand Selection to Line` command keybinding (ctrl+L) in your User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap:

```
    { "keys": ["alt+l"], "command": "chain", "args": {
     "commands": [
        ["expand_selection", {"to": "line"}],
        ["move", {"by": "characters", "extend": true, "forward": false}],
        ]
        }
    }
```

In this case, you can't have two command/arg lines directly in the same binding, so we go through the "chain" command.

Comment: This is great, thanks! One note: if you're selecting the last line in the file with no trailing new line (shame on you!) the selection will miss the last character of the last line. This is presumably since this command "deselects" a single character at the end?